# What means "preserves angles"

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to understand conformal mapping.

> A function is conformal if it preserves angles. 
>   So $(g \circ \gamma_1)'(z_1) = (g \circ \gamma_2)'(z_1)$

I'm reading a book, and just after the definition, there is information that $\bar{Z}$ is not conformal, as it revers angles and $z^2$ is conformal on $\lbrace Re(z) > 0\rbrace$. I understand why $z^3$ won't be conformal on that set (it reverses angles after "full circle"), but I cannot understand why $z^2$ is.

I see that $z^2 : \lbrace Re(z) > 0\rbrace \to \mathbb{C} \smallsetminus (-\infty, 0]$, so angles are not reversed, but I don't get how they are preserved.
It looks for me like every angle is greater. Angle of $\pi/4$ ($\gamma_1=(x, x)$ and $\gamma_2=(x, -x)$ for $x > 0$) is mapped to $\pi/2$.

So, what "preserves angles" means? As I cannot see how $z^2$ may preserves something. (Below picture from Complex Analysis T. Gamelin)
[image]

Comment: $z^2$ is not conformal at zero and you measure angles around zero in your example; $z^2$ is conformal around any non zero point but you need to have angles centered at such points

Comment: As Conrad says, $z\mapsto z^2$ is not conformal at $z=0$ since the derivative vanishes at $z=0$.

Comment: @Conrad I see the root of my problem, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Conformal maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_map) preserve angles at a microscopic level; that is, if two curves intersect at an angle $\alpha$ in the source space, they also intersect at the same angle $\alpha$ in the destination space. This means their [Jacobian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) is a constant times a rotation (that is, a radially scaled rotation matrix).

In $\mathbb{C}$, if $f(z)$ differentiable at $z_0$ and $f'(z_0)\ne0$, $f(z)$ is conformal at $z_0$. In fact, near $z_0$,
$$
f(z)=f(z_0)+f'(z_0)(z-z_0)+o(z-z_0)
$$
so the constant of the radial scale is $|f'(z_0)|$ and the angle of the rotation is $\arg(f(z_0))$.

Here are three examples of conformal mappings of an equilateral triangle in $\mathbb{C}$. At each vertex, there is a small copy of the original triangle so that the angles can more easily be compared.

[image]

Here are three examples of conformal mappings of an isoceles right triangle in $\mathbb{C}$. At each vertex, there is a small copy of the original triangle so that the angles can more easily be compared.

[image]

Comment: "radially scaled rotation" - So it does not mean that $\alpha$ does not change, but that $\alpha$ is multiplied by constant? I added picture to my question to better describe my problem. Angle between two visible lines seems to change under $z^2$ map. But I can see that angle is scaled. Am I right?

Comment: No, $\alpha$ remains unchanged where the mapping is conformal. In $\mathbb{C}$, if $f(z)$ differentiable at $z_0$ and $f'(z_0)\ne0$, $f(z)$ is conformal at $z_0$.

Comment: I have added small copies of the original triangle at the vertices to show more clearly that the angles are preserved.

Comment: Thank you for the pictures, they are really helpful. I spent some time on it, and I think I understand it now.